# Limiting "Free Shipping" to Lower 48 States in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-2.0, free-shipping

I'm trying to limit the free shipping rule to just the Lower 48 States (i.e. not including Alaska and Hawaii). I've searched around for guides on how to do this is Magento 2 and all I saw are guides for Magento 1.* by using something called "Shopping Cart Price Rules"

Is this not achievable in Magento 2? Or I am missing something?

I've opened every single tabs in `Stores > Configuration` and did not see anything even close to "Shopping Cart Price Rules"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in to Magento Admin, **MARKETING** > **Cart Price Rules**

[image]

And then, try to create new cart price rules.

Comment: That would explain why I can't find it in `Stores > Configuration`. Thanks!

Comment: @khoa, I created cart price rules but it's not working as expected. Should I enabled free shipping method for this cart price rule to work? or any insight on this?

Comment: Any solution for this? Reply

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to Magento Admin, MARKETING > Cart Price Rules and create cart price rules.

Before that, please give some higher number for minimum order amount in configuration -> free shipping.

[image]

Then follow the things in the below screenshot.

[image]

Then it will work sure.